# React: passing parent state to child when the parent state is sourced and modified from external classes acting as a property in the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm not sure how to exactly word it out on the title, since the problem is way too specific in my scenario, but anyway basically I have two external classes similar to below:

```
class Config {
    public level: number = 1; //this is a sample state I want to pass

    //sets level
    public setLevel(level: number){
        this.level = level;
    }
}

//wrapper class that uses Config class as a property
class Manager {
    public config: Config = new Config();

    //invokes Config.setLevel() here, but wrapped
    public nextLevel(level: number){
        this.config.setLevel(level)
    }
}
```

And then my react components are:

```
//here is my parent component using Manager
class ParentComp extends React.Component<any, any>{
    public mngr: Manager = new Manager(); //uses Manager as a property

    constructor(props: any){
        super(props);

        this.state = { config: this.mngr.config }; //adds the Manager instance's property as a state
    }

    public render(){
        //passes the state to a child component
        return(
            <div> <ChildComp level={this.state.config.level}/> </div>
        )
    }

    //this is where I simulate changing the level property using the external class(es)
   componentDidMount(){
        setTimeout(()=>{
           this.mngr.nextLevel(2); //invoke external class method that changes the source object
           console.log('1 sec has passed and a new level has been set.')
        }, 1000)
    }
}

class ChildComp extends React.Component<any, any>{
    constructor(props: any){
        super(props);
        this.state = {level: props.level} //uses the prop to the child's state
    }
}
```

`componentDidMount` on `ParentComp` does change `ParentComp.config.level`, based on the React dev tools, but not `ChildComp.level`.

Why and what to do? I am coming from a Vue background and usually Vue automatically handles these things. I don't understand why it isn't working for React.

Comment: You can lift state up to the parent from the child

Comment: @user93, but that's not what I am looking for. I want to propagate the state from the parent to the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually call `setState()` which is a trigger to get the component to re-render, so the Child component would never receive updated props in this scenario. Thus, no changes are reflected.

You might be able to just trigger a re-render with the updated config value, assuming it is actually updated via `this.mgr.nextLevel(2)`

```
public componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
       this.mngr.nextLevel(2); //invoke external class method that changes the source object
       this.setState({
          config: this.state.config
       })
    }, 1000)
}
```

In reference from comments, you can also trigger a state-update in the child-component to reflect these changes.

In **ChildComp.js** write the following:

```
public componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(prevProps.level !== this.props.level){
      this.setState({
         level: this.props.level
      })
   }
}
```

> Do I really have to keep explicitly calling
>   `setState()` every time I want a React component to react to object
>   changes? Doesn't it automatically bind stuff on the constructor when I
>   did `this.state = {config: this.mngr.config}`?

Yes, you do have to call `setState()` every time you want the component to reflect some UI change. Doesn't matter if the change is done implicitly or not, the component will not display those changes unless you call the aforementioned method.

Comment: Based on the react dev tools, this does seem to change my `ChildComp` `props`, but not the `state`.

Comment: @AbanaClara just to be clear, you implemented my above code and it does update props but not state correct?

Comment: Correct. Literally the same. Of course, my original code has lots more irl but the concept compared to my post lies the same.

Comment: @AbanaClara I see. Can you try including the snippet I just added. That might help you out.

Comment: This does it. I tried this before your answer but I got stuck on an endless loop. Adding a flag taking from the lifecycle's supplied parameter does it. I really need to look up on docs better. Thank you!

Comment: @AbanaClara you're welcome! Glad that worked for you haha.

Comment: Quick question, do I really have to keep explicitly calling `setState({})` everytime I want a React component to react to object changes? Doesn't it automatically bind stuff on the constructor when I did `this.state = {config: this.mngr.config}`? You can add this on your answer

Comment: Yes, you do have to call `setState()` everytime you want the component to reflect some UI change. Doesn't matter if the change is done implicitly or not, the component will not display those changes unless you call the aforementioned method. @AbanaClara

Answer (score 2):

You didn't use `setState` property in your implementation , that is why there is no change.